# org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException : Request processing failed For MockMVC in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, exception, junit, mockito, mockmvc

When I tried to write negative unit test case for getting UnauthenticatedException which is user defined exception, After executing mockmvc code  it is throwing me an exception  back and test case is failed.

> *(org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
> com.exception.UnauthenticatedException: Invalid Credentials!)**

```
@Test
public void loginUser_NotAuthorised() throws Exception {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("user");
    user.setPassword("");
        when(loginService.loginUser(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class)))
                .thenThrow(new UnauthenticatedException("Invalid Credentials!"));

         mockMvc.perform(post("/login").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)).characterEncoding("utf-8").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))            
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized()).andDo(print()).andReturn();
}
```

This is the exception received

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.exception.UnauthenticatedException: Invalid Credentials!
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
at com.tests.controller.LoginControllerTest.loginUser_NotAuthorised(LoginControllerTest.java:169)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: com.exception.UnauthenticatedException: Invalid Credentials!
at com.controller.LoginController.loginUser(LoginController.java:28)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
... 67 more
```

I also had doubt, what all possible ways of unit test cases can be written for combined Mockito and MockMVC and can you also share resources and example projects for the same?

**LoginTestController class with all imports**

```
 package com.tests.controller;

    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsString;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
    import static 
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
    import static 
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
    import static 
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.put;
    import static 
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
    import static 
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
    import static 
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
    import org.mockito.Matchers;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
    
    import com.beans.User;
    import com.controller.LoginController;
    import com.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl;
    import com.exception.UnauthenticatedException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(value = LoginController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { LoginController.class })
    
    public class LoginControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    LoginServiceImpl loginService;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    public void loginUser_NotAuthorised() throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("user");
        user.setPassword("");
        when(loginService.loginUser(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class)))
                .thenThrow(new UnauthenticatedException("Invalid Credentials!"));
        mockMvc.perform(post("/login").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)).characterEncoding("utf-8").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message").value("Invalid Cr

    edentials!")).andDo(print())
                    .andReturn();
        }
    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your expect to below one

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/login").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(user)).characterEncoding("utf-8").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))            
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized()).andExpect(
                MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.message").value("Invalid Credentials!"));
```

Comment: I have tried this receiving same exception (org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.exception.UnauthenticatedException: Invalid Credentials!)

Comment: could you update your whole test class, here with imports?

Answer (score 0):

I know its very old thread,

I had same issue as well, the culprit here is that your services implementation Mock object

**Instead of this**

```
  when(loginService.loginUser(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class)))
            .thenThrow(new UnauthenticatedException("Invalid Credentials!"));
```

**Use this**

```
  LoginServiceImpl loginService = Mockito.mock(LoginServiceImpl.class)
  Mockito.doThrow(new UnauthenticatedException("Invalid Credentials!"))
         .when(loginService)
         .loginUser(ArgumentMatchers.any(User.class))
```

If you see above, you should mock your `impl` class and then pass that mock object to `when` and call your method.

It worked for me.